# How to make Google Cloud Storage CORS header consistent over appspot URIs

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've set CORS headers to my custom subdomain bucket on Google Cloud Storage with this json:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

This works great for my subdomain: http://cdn.example.com/ however I also noticed you can access this bucket similar to Google AppEngine instances through: http://cdn.example.appspot.com/ and http://cdn-dot-example.appspot.com/. Unfortunately the CORS headers didn't carry over. Is there an additional parameter I missed when using `gsutil cors set` to make the CORS setting propagate to all URIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of this writing the `appspot` mirror isn't supposed to serve Cloud Storage content at all, so you shouldn't rely on it. I received an email from the Google Cloud Team saying this.